# Keep path prefix for #include after target_include_directories in CMake

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I have a CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
target_include_directories(targetA PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../external/glm/)
```

The `external` folder has multiple sub-folders. Before `target_include_directories` changes headers of `targetA` looked like:

```
#include <glm/something.h>
```

Now headers of `targetA` looks like:

```
#include <something.h>
```

Is there any way to keep `glm` prefix for include?
I understand that there is an option to put the folder `glm` in a subfolder `glm`.
But is there any other option?

Comment: Just use `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../external/` in `target_include_directories`?

Comment: It's not an option. I has other subfolders in `external` folder. I don't want to include them all.

Comment: ***I don't want to include them all*** That will not include them all. It will add only the `external` folder to your includes.

Comment: Is there an option to include *only* `external/glm` but keep `glm` as prefix for `include`-s ?

Comment: "Is there an option to include only `external/glm` but keep `glm` as prefix for `include`" - No, there is no such option. It is not CMake who doesn't want to implement such feature. It is **standard compilers** who doesn't support such feature.

Comment: Technically you could create a custom target that first copies the entire `glm` directory to an otherwise empty subdirectory of `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`, add a dependency to that custom target and then set the `target_include_directories` to the copy of the glm headers. But I'd rather reorganize the `external` dir so that isn't necessary.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details about your use case. Add all information or clarification to the question instead of using comments for this purpose. Show an example structure of directories and files. Please explain in more detail why you don't want to use `target_include_directories(targetA PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../external/)`. Of course an `#include "foo/bar.h"` might find a file `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../external/foo/bar.h`. Why would this be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to keep glm prefix for include? I understand that there is an option to put the folder glm in a subfolder glm. But is there any other option?

No. Not that I'm aware of (as long as you insist on keeping your directory layout completely unchanged). This just how most compilers do include directories.

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html
- https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#include-path-management
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories